# Spatial Query with distance restriction on data

Tags: database-design, solr, geolocation, geospatial, spatial

I am building an app with geo-location capability. I am currently stucked on what's the best way to store and query data.
Here's my usual use-case.

Person A adds an image with geo-location. Aside from the geo-location data, he/she also added flag that says his/her image is only visible to users within 1 mile.

Now, my question is, what's the best way to store this information so that another Person can see all images near his current location while respecting the restriction of the images stored, e.g. visible only for 1 mile, visible only for 2 miles, etc..

Comment: Are you restricted to solr or would another solution be possible

Comment: i'm open on trying out a different data storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solr has geospatial search capabilities (which have been considerably enhanced recently via the Java Topology Suite library). The [Solr documentation](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpatialSearch#geofilt_-_The_distance_filter) has an example of using the distance filter that allows you to find anything with distance d of some point, eg,

```
&q=*:*&fq={!geofilt sfield=location}&pt=41.38,2.18&d=5
```

where q would be the non-geospatial part of the search, sfield is your location field, pt is the point (which has to be in lat/lon, and is Barcelona in the above example) and d is the distance field. You could substitute your attribute for how far away an image can be seen for the d parameter.

Note there is also the geodist function, which allows you to sort by distance, if you wanted to highlight closer things.

Another approach you could use would be to use a spatial database and store the location data as a point field. As an example from Postgres/Postgis you could use the http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html function, which allows you to search for everything within a distance of some point. Postgres/GIS uses a R-tree index for [spatial indexing](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.3SVN/ch04.html#id2726625), which allows for very fast and efficient searches of this nature. It also has good full-text search capabilities for the attribute part.

```
select * from images where ST_DWithin( point, st_setsrid(st_makepoint(2.1, 41.38), 4326), 5);
```

You can so similar things with Oracle and SQL Server (and to a lesser extent with MySQL). This approach might seem more complicated than the Solr approach, and if you are sticking to searches in lat/lon of the give me all images matching this attribute within distance d of this point then SOLR will certainly do what you want, but if you want to consider more advanced spatial functionality in the future, and take advantage of other database features, you might want to consider the spatial database approach.

Comment: Thanks for the answer John. I am familiar with using solr and I'm just thinking if it's the best way to do it that way. My search will be spatial search + attribute search. I've looked into postgres/postgis as well but I haven't done any benchmark on which is faster, solr or postgresql/postgis, as I don't have a lot of data to do the benchmark.

Comment: Apologies for the solr presumption. In my experience, text search in Postgres via tsearch and various contrib packages is quite powerful, but requires a fair amount of fine tuning, whereas 
Solr (Lucene) more or less works out of the box. Postgres and Solr are, of course, very different beasts from a data storage viewpoint and the spatial capabilities of Postgis are considerably greater, even with the inclusion of JTS in Solr. Ultimately, you can only really decide with expected use case testing, which as you have said, is problematic in your case.